# Session Access and Async Callbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asynchronous, delegates

Ok, so I have a bunch of async web service calls that I make on the landing page of my website . I want to set the results of these calls to session so that I can use them later, but I can't because `HttpContext.Current` is null in the callback. Basically,  I want to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Something()
{
    GetLoans();              //each of these is async
    GetPartInfo();           //and sets its result to session
    GetOtherAsyncStuff();    //(or at least it needs to)
    //lots of other stuff
    Return View();
}
```

Where `GetLoans()` looks like this:

```
public IAsyncResult GetLoans()
{
    IAsyncResult _ar;
    GetLoansDelegate d_Loans = new GetLoansDelegate(GetLoansAsync);
    _ar = d_Loans.BeginInvoke(parameter1,parameter2, GetLoansCallback, new object()); //new object() is just a placeholder for the real parameters im putting there
    return _ar;
}
```

Which asynchronously invokes `GetLoansAsync`, whose callback is `GetLoansCallback()`, shown here:

```
private void GetLoansCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
    GetLoansDelegate caller = (GetLoansDelegate)result.AsyncDelegate;
    List<Loan> loans = caller.EndInvoke(ar);

    Session["Loans"] = loans;   //this call blows up, since HttpContext.Current is null
}
```

I can't implement a custom session provider, so I have to stick with what I've got there. So as it stands, I can't set anything to session in my async callback. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You could create essentially a session of your own (a static dictionary) and then set your results in that.  Make sure your access to this data structure is thread safe.

Comment: @StefanH yeah, I thought about that. Right now I'm trying out just declaring a couple of variables at the controller level and setting them to the results of the async calls, and then setting those to session back on the UI thread after I use the `WaitOne()` method of the async wait handle. I'll let you know how that goes

Comment: I believe static objects are shared application wise between all clients unlike a session which is unique to each client. I discourage the use of static objects if the data contained shouldn't be shared between users.

Comment: @user1121108 Sorry if I provided any confusion.  Yes, the static objects are shared across the app domain, they would need to be thread safe.  What I meant by "create your own session" is that you would need to use a user key (perhaps store it in the actual session) for storing data on a per user basis.

Comment: @StefanH Yes, got your point now. Indeed that looks like a good idea.

Comment: @StefanH so, going down that path (but maybe straying a little), would there be anything to stop me from declaring a `Dictionary<string,List<Loan>>` (where string is the key) at the controller level, and then initializing it (new Dictionary...()) at the action level to keep it cleared out as much as possible, since I really only need the data to persist through this one action

Comment: @StefanH does that make sense at all? before the end of the action, I will have set the stuff from my mini-session to actual session, so I don't need it anymore. Thus the `new Dictionary...()` at the action level. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120331172304/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx).

Basically, it says that `HttpContext` cannot be available upon the work completion (i.e. in the callback) and it looks like that you will have to move the session operations into the `GetLoansAsync` method.